# How to share variable between nested directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When one directive (call it `el2`) is nested within another (call it `el1`), I cannot access variables "locally declared" in `el1` (e.g. variables produced by `ng-repeat`, `ng-init` etc) from `el2`.

[This fiddle demonstrates the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/zL47Ltsr/5/). Code follows:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

// define blue `el1` element which contains an `el2` child:
myApp.directive('el1', function() { 
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope) {
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-init="value1 = 1;">' +
            'value1: {{ value1 }}' +
            ' <el2></el2>' +
            '</div>',
        scope: {
        }
    };
});

// define green `el2` element:
myApp.directive('el2', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope) {
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<span ng-init="value2 = 2;">' +
            'value1: {{ value1 || "UNDEFINED" }} value2: {{ value2 }}</span>',
        scope: {
            value1: '='
        }
    };
});
```

How can I access `value1` in the `el2` directive? Is there any way that does not involve modifying the scope explicitly through the `link` function or `controller`?

Comment: Is el2 only used inside el1? If so, maybe having two directives is not the best thing, otherwise: could value1 be passed as an attribute?

Comment: have you tried this  $parent.value1 in el2 directive. http://jsfiddle.net/zL47Ltsr/6/

Comment: @Grissom That works! But seems rather icky... Especially in a more complex case where it might be the parent's parent or when you might not even know which of your ancestors gave you the value?

Comment: @FabioF. Great solution. In fact, that is what I tried out first and then forgot about. The thing is that it did not work in one case because I forgot to change attribute names (called `typeId` and `actionType`) from camelCase to dash-delimiting! Stupid me! Do you want to post the solution?

Comment: @Domi you can answer yourself with the solution you've found ;)

Comment: @FabioF. You proposed it here first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So again: The problem is to share a variable between two nested directives.

The solution is simple and requires two and a half steps:

1. Pass the name of the shared variable as an attribute to the inner (e.g. `my-var="value1"`)
2. Add that attribute to the inner directives `scope` set (e.g. `scope: { myVar: '=' }`)

   - Make sure, you are using `dash-delimiting` case for the attribute name (e.g. `my-var` instead of `myVar`.

[Updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zL47Ltsr/11/).

Now, the inner directive can access the outer directive's value of `x.val` as `myValue1`. As expected, the binding goes both ways.

Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

var x = {
    val: 1
};

// define blue `el1` element which contains an `el2` child:
myApp.directive('el1', function() { 
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.x = x;
        },
        template: '<div>' +
            'x.val: {{ x.val }}' +
            ' <el2 my-value1="x.val"></el2>' +
            '</div>'
    };
});

// define green `el2` element:
myApp.directive('el2', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<span ng-init="value2 = 2;">' +
            'myValue1: {{ myValue1 || "UNDEFINED" }} ' +
            '<button ng-click="myValue1 = myValue1+1;">+</button>' +
            'value2: {{ value2 }}' +
            '</span>',
        scope: {
            myValue1: '='
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks go to [Fabio F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343794/fabio-f) for pointing out that variable names can be simply transferred via attribute.